# How to implement a simple system call in kernel 2.6.26?

Tags: linux-kernel, system-calls

I gone through many questions here and in the other website I still having following questions  .

I am implementing a simple system call ,for this the files I have changed as follows

```
 1. /arch/x86/kernel/syscal_table_32_S
 2. /include/asm-x86/unistd_32.h
 3. /include/linux/syscalls.h
```

I have doubt in the 2nd file because this ,I am not sure this file(/include/asm-x86/unistd_32.h) to modify or any other file ,as I know the file which containing the system calls number,We have to add our sys call and the last number + 1 ,the doubt here is this file(`/include/asm-x86/unistd_32.h)` doesn't contain the limit line (`#define NR_syscalls <last syscall no + 1>`) but there is another file (`/include/asm-sh/unistd_32.h`),which contain the syscall numbers and also the limit line.

So ,kindly tell me which files to modify with a simple example.

Answer (score 2):

I implemented new syscalls on the linux-kernel 3.2 and modified following files:

```
1. /arch/x86/kernel/syscal_table_32.S
2. /arch/x86/kernel/syscal_table_64.S
3. /arch/x86/include/asm/unistd_32.h - contains NR_syscalls for ia32
4. /arch/x86/include/asm/unistd_64.h
5. /arch/x86/include/asm/<new_file_with_syscall>
6. /arch/x86/include/asm/Makefile
```

The syscall itself I called with `syscall(NUMBER_OF_SYSCALL)` function.